How to pass custom config options for xdebug settings in PhpStorm?
In order to solve another problem, I want to manually provide certain configuration options for the Run Debug configuration.
In PhpStorm, at
Settings > PHP > Debug > Settings

there is a flag for
Pass require configuration options through command line (still need to enable debug extension manually)

For troubleshooting purposes, I disabled that flag, yet I don't see where to add my custom configuration options instead.
How to add custom configuration options?
I want to provide custom values for the flags:

dxdebug.mode
dxdebug.client_port
dxdebug.client_hos

How to?

You can pass additional params to your PHP interpreter at PHP Interpreter screen (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-remote-interpreters.html -- see the "Configuration options" field on Step #5 screenshot). The -d option will be used for them. Params added there will take over what PhpStorm actually detects for Xdebug (as they will be added later in the command line).

NOTE: Since it's a PHP Interpreter options, they will be used in CLI environment only. Means: will not affect your Apache/nginx/etc web server but will be used for CLI commands, PHPUnit tests, PHP's built-in web server and similar -- any tools where PHP executable can be used directly by the IDE.

These config options are read through the php.ini within your WSL instance.
Add this in your relevant php.ini or 20-xdebug.ini, e.g.: /etc/php/8.3/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini:
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.client_host=xdebug://gateway
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_port=9003

